# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

"Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a meassure function!" Error in React-Native Expo. Has something to do with my map in a component I believe, I was just returning an h2 tag with the info, then I realized it needed to be a Text, put it in a Text instead and got this new error. People online said it needed to be a View as well, that didn't seem to fix it though.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function ListTasks(props) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        {" "}
        {props.tasks.map(task => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text>{task.Task}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}{" "}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

```
export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tasks: [
        { Completed: false, Task: "Drink water" },
        { Completed: false, Task: "Work on React-Native app" },
        { Completed: false, Task: "Clean bedroom" }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListTasks tasks={this.state.tasks} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the curly braces `{"  "}` are causing the issue. May I know the purpose of these braces which are wrapping the map?

Comment: That's just something prettier does automatically, when I remove them it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try to access the `props` by using `this.props`, i.e `this.props.tasks` and remove the word `props` next to classname

Comment: if you do that you get an TypeError, that this.props.tasks is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the simple ";" at the end of the return in the map that prettier was auto putting in..

```
<Text>
        {" "}
        {props.tasks.map(task => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text>{task.Task}</Text>
            </View>
          )
        })}{" "}
      </Text>
```